# Is an AVD encapsulated in a single folder? Can it be replicated?

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

After somehow managing to create my first AVD, toy with it and "contaminate" with lots installs and uninstalls, it's time for me to start experimenting in a more controlled manner.

My initial thought is to create a "master AVD" which is very clean, from the beginning, and do all kinds of installs and experimentation on **copies** of it. So that I can always have some "known state" reference point.

My question is whether this is as simple as duplicating the MasterAVD folder and renaming it?

I noticed that my first AVD folder is accompanied by .INI file (on Windows XP) with the same basename. Should this .INI file be copied as well?

Are there additional requirements for AVD duplication?

Comment: You can reset and AVD to its default values in the SDK manager, when you click "start..." a dialog pops up with an option to wipe user data.

Comment: Thanks and +1. This is a great answer, although it doesn't answer the exact question that I asked. Do you know whether "wipe user data" is equivalent to bringing the AVD to the pristine original state immediately after creating the AVD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the answer is... YES. I just tried that (duplicating the MasterAVD folder + its associated .INI files, renaming them, and editing the .INI to point to the MasterAVD folder) and it works.